# Change Apache2 server directory

Tags: linux, apache2

I have recently just started ubuntu on my virtual machine. I am new to linux.
I intend to temporarily host my development website on there

I have gotten the FTP to work
I have Apache2 installed and running.

I changed the default folder for the webpage

the basic web page does show up and everything seems to work.

However for some reason the CSS does not show up?

When I inspect the code with firebug it tells me tat I do not have permission to view the file.

how do I fix this?

Comment: Likely a permissions problem on the file. Can you run `ls -l` in the directory with your CSS?

Comment: yes, just lists the css files in that folder

Comment: I'm looking for the permissions. There should be a `-rwx------` or similar before each file. Could you post that?

Comment: for the css folder it is drwxrwxr-x
for the actual css files it is -rw------

Comment: I meant the files in the CSS folder.

Comment: actual css files it is -rw------

Comment: K that worked. but the files in the subsequent folder needed to be changed as well. is it possible to make the folder such that all the files placed into that folder(and subsequent folders) will have the new permissions?

Comment: You can change all files recursively (see my answer). Otherwise, it's not possible (afaik) to force all new files to be readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, you mentioned that your CSS files are `-rw-------` (600), which means that only your user has read or write permissions.

In order for Apache, or anyone else, to be able to read those files, you'll have to set the read permission for all users. Something like this should work:

```
chmod +r *
```

If you want to do this for all files recursively, add the `-R` flag.

```
chmod -R +r *
```

References:

- [chmod](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)

Comment: Awesome thanks. Think I got it to do what I need it to do.